# Set margin Left for different browser sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have set margin left for my sliding form to my screen. but its managable only for my screen, not for other screen size. I want to set Margin Left According to different Screen sizes, so how should i do ??

Comment: I think margin:auto will work .

Comment: Have you tried relative units, like `%` or `em`?

Comment: Depending on your layout, you can set the margin to be a percentage of your element's container, or use media queries to define specific breaking points for your layout (or a combination of both).

Comment: I will go with Anthony and will suggest to use relative units like `%` or `em`.

Comment: yaa mr. Anthony. i used it. but not successed . do you have any other Idea ??